# How can I launch a command from terminal and then close the terminal?

Tags: command-line, code

I ran `scratch-text-editor` in terminal, but now I want to close the terminal without closing scratch.

Is this possible, if so; how?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use:

1. `nohup`

   ```
   nohup scratch-text-editor /path/to/file &
   ```

   Then close terminal with `Ctrl+D`

   If you want direct in single command: Use `exit` at the end of the command. like,

   ```
   nohup scratch-text-editor /path/to/file & exit
   ```
2. `setsid`

   ```
   setsid scratch-text-editor /path/to/file ; exit
   ```
3. `disown`

   ```
   scratch-text-editor /path/to/file & disown ; exit
   ```
4. All in one command:

   ```
   (scratch-text-editor /path/to/file &) ; exit
   ```

Comment: @Tim please try your answer once again :)

Comment: without `nohup` you cant stop process with just &

Comment: btw @Tim since you are asking for `command` can I add alternative commands in my answer?

Answer (score 4):

In the future use this command:

```
scratch-text-editor /file/to/open.txt
```

for this:

```
scratch-text-editor /file/to/open.txt &
```

Note the `&` on the end there. That will start it as a separate process.

Now to close the terminal, simply hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>.

---

If you forget to use `&` then you can detach it. First press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> to suspend the program. This can crash some, but it is unlikely.

Then type `bg` to send it to background, and then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> as above.

As a side note, instead of `bg` you can use `%`. This simply brings it back into the terminal.

Comment: why Ctrl+D ?...........

Comment: @Ravan `D` is for Detach? Or do you mean why not just close it? That will close the application too

Comment: Actually in the first case you could still close the terminal. Go to the terminal and hit Ctrl+Z (suspend), then run 'bg' to resume the process in the background. Now you can use Ctrl+D as mentioned to close the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Simply detach the process from terminal's process to its parent by:
`command-to-run & disown`

Comment: Mind explaining the downvote?

Comment: The downvote was because this answer adds nothing -  this is covered in previous answers.

Answer (score 0):

This should work with any app opened from the terminal.

Type:

```
 scratch-text-editor
```

After Scratch opens, type:

```
Ctrl + z
```

This will halt the process, but not close Scratch.

Next, type:

```
bg
```

This will move Scratch's process to the background.

Now, finally type:

```
disown
```

That's it.